# /usr/bin/node : Permission denied

Tags: node.js, permissions, executable, nvm

On Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed NodeJS v8.9.3, using NVM. I ran the installation as `root`, and so node was installed here:

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node
```

In the hope of making it accessible to non-root users, I created a soft link at `/usr/bin/node`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      40 янв 18 11:58 node -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node
```

The node file itself has executable permissions for all users:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 500 500 35200878 дек  8 17:09 /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node
```

When I access node as root, all works perfectly:

```
# node -v && which node
v8.9.3
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node
```

Any attempt to access it as a non-root user fails:

```
$ node -v
The program 'node' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
$ /usr/bin/node -v
bash: /usr/bin/node: Permission denied
```

What changes do I have to make where to allow non-root users access to node?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you remove your current installation and install using apt-get instead. Here is tutorial from official Ubuntu website: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

That way of installing will make node accessible for root as well as all other users by default.

Also, keep in mind that:

> Because of a conflict with another package, the executable from the
>   Ubuntu repositories is called **nodejs** instead of **node**. Keep this in
>   mind as you are running software.

Here is another good resource on installing nodejs:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod 755 /usr/bin/node`. This will give read & exec permission to all users on your system

Comment: `/usr/bin/node` already has `777` permissions, as my second script extract shows